# git auto complete freezes terminal when password required

Tags: debian, git, linux

When executing a command such as this

```
git pull origin BRANCH-1
```

and hitting *tab* (auto complete)

I get a password prompt like so:

```
git pull origin BRANCH-1Password:
```

Then the terminal freezes. The cursor blinks but it would not accept any input from the keyboard. I can't Ctrl+c or enter the password.

The only option is to close down the terminal which is sending me nuts.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl+J seems to do the trick. It adds a LF allowing me to break the deadlock.